# I need to test this code, but when writing a trigger, I get an invalid type

Tags: apex, visualforce, package

I need help. I am currently trying to test this code before uploading

```
public class CoreValuesExt
{
ApexPages.StandardController sc;
public boolean readonly {get; set;}
public Core_Values__c cv {get; set;}
public integer countEdit = 1;
public string buttonValue {get; set;}
public integer recordScan;

public CoreValuesExt(ApexPages.StandardController sc)
{
    this.sc = sc;
    cv = new Core_Values__c();
    cv.Account__c = sc.getid();

    readonly = true;
    buttonValue = 'Edit';
    recordScan = [SELECT COUNT() FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Account__c = :cv.Account__c];
   if (recordScan != 0){
   cv = [SELECT id, HSE__c, Professionalism_Integrity__c, Quality_Accuracy__c, Technology_Innovation__c, Timeliness__c, Value_for_money__c FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Account__c = :cv.Account__c];
    }

}

public ApexPages.PageReference Save()
{
    return sc.Save();
}

public void ApplyAction()
{
    countEdit++;
    Integer modolus = Math.mod(countEdit, 2);
    String total = cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c;
    if(modolus == 0)
    {
        readonly = false;
        buttonValue = 'Save';
    }
    else
    {
        if(total != 'nullnullnullnullnullnull')
           {
        if (recordScan == 0){
        insert cv;
        readonly = true;
        buttonValue = 'Edit';
        }
        else
        {
        update cv;
        readonly = true;
        buttonValue = 'Edit';
        }
        }
    }  

}
```

}

With this trigger.

```
trigger CoreValuesTrigger on Core_Values__c (before insert) {

Core_Values__c cvs = Trigger.new;
CoreValuesExt.ApplyAction(cvs);

}
```

But when I try to save, I get a message saying:

> Illegal assignment from List to
>   CoreValuesExt__Core_Values__c at line 3 column 1

"

How do I go through with this? I need help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit odd of a construction

1. You have a trigger trying to use the constructor of a VF controller extension
2. Triggers get invoked when DML is done, and this can occur from many places, including clients that have nothing to do with user interaction though a VF page - such as Data Loader, REST/Web service clients, batch classes, future methods, etc. As such, certain VF context won;t be present and can lead to errors (such as using `ApexPages` methods).

Your specific error is because

```
trigger CoreValuesTrigger on Core_Values__c (before insert) {

Core_Values__c cvs = Trigger.new;
CoreValuesExt.ApplyAction(cvs);

}
```

1. Trigger.new is always a `List<Core_Values__c>`, never a singleton.
2. Hence assigning a list to a singleton generates the error.

Since a `standardcontroller` constructor would never be passed a list of sobjects, it can never accept `Trigger.new`.  And don't even think about passing `Trigger.new[0]` - all triggers need to be bulkified; avoiding this rule leads to a hole that you will inevitably have to dig yourself out of.. Use best practices from the get-go.

Lastly, SObject names ending in plural would be unusual (`Core_Values__c`). The object should represent one thing (Account, Contact, Opportunity, Order, Quote, Case, ...)

If the problem is testing -- then you do this with testmethods in test classes. See the Visualforce Developer Guide for examples on how to test controller extensions.  You don't write triggers.  Instead, you mock test data and pass to the controller class.

You are going to have to rethink your design and use of triggers versus controllers. More information is required to go further

Comment: Ok, I ran a test. I saw in the Apex Test Execution page that in this test class, there was an Invalid ID. System.StringException Invalid ID: 6. on line 5.

Answer (score 0):

For this code. There was an invalid id of 6 on line 5.

@isTest
private class CoreValuesExtTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateCoreValues() {
       Account sc = new Account(id='00128000002fgxl');
       Core_Values__c cv = new Core_Values__c(Account__c='6', HSE__c='6', Professionalism_Integrity__c='6', Quality_Accuracy__c='6', Technology_Innovation__c='6', Value_for_Money__c='6', Timeliness__c='6');
       System.debug(cv.Account__c + cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c);

```
   // Insert book
   CoreValuesExt testCv = new CoreValuesExt(new ApexPages.StandardController(sc));
   testCv.ApplyAction();

   // Retrieve the new book
   cv = [SELECT id, Account__c, HSE__c,Professionalism_Integrity__c,Quality_Accuracy__c,Technology_Innovation__c,Value_for_Money__c,Timeliness__c FROM Core_Values__c WHERE Id=:'00128000002fgxl'];
   System.debug(cv.Account__c + cv.HSE__c + cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c + cv.Quality_Accuracy__c + cv.Technology_Innovation__c + cv.Value_for_Money__c + cv.Timeliness__c);

   // Test that the trigger correctly updated the grades
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.HSE__c);
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.Professionalism_Integrity__c);
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.Quality_Accuracy__c);
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.Technology_Innovation__c);
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.Value_for_Money__c);
   System.assertEquals('6', cv.Timeliness__c);


}
```

}

Comment: is this an answer or a question? if a question, please amend your original post at the top with the updated code

Comment: Please close this thread,  Problem solved. Thank you